# Ionic framework - Text box without opening a new window

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

After clicking on the textbox I am getting a new window . How do I achieve the same functionality without opening a new window?

```
<div class="form_element_grid auto_fill_info">
    <label>Company <em>*</em></label>
       <div>
           <ion-select-autocomplete multiselect="false"
                       output="models.deliveryCompanyName"
                       header="Choose Company"
                       callback="companySelected(models.deliveryCompanyName)"
                       label-key="name"
                       addnew="true"
          add-callback="createDeliveryCompany(name, phone, callback)"
                        options="deliveryCompanies"
                        readonly="readonly" />
       </div>
   <input type="text" 
          ng-model="models.deliveryCompanyName.name" 
          id="deliveryCompanyName" 
          callback="companySelected(models.deliveryCompanyName)" 
          name="deliveryCompanyName" 
          class="hidden" required/>

      <p class="error-label" ng-show="deliveryForm.deliveryCompanyName.$invalid">
         Required
      </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? please elaborate your problem?

Comment: Well, right now after clicking on the textbox i am getting one pop up window. So without opening a pop up window i need to achieve this same functionality.

Comment: what functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: The above code performs some functionality after opening a pop up window.. can you please go through the code. I need to achieve the same functionality without opening a pop up window..